# What are the vEthernet Switches in Windows and can / should I get rid of them?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 machine which I use with Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 and Hyper-V.

The installation of Hyper-V is new and after enabling it my "network connections" looks like this:
[image]

When I run `ipconfig` I can see:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (New Virtual Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : attlocal.net
```

Is my first and main ethernet adapter.  My actual main adapter, the one called "Ethernet" does not even show up on the list.

Questions:

- What are these vEthernet Switches?
- Why is my computer not using the native Ethernet switch anymore?
- Are there performance implications do this?
- What are the various 172.x.x.x IP addresses assigned to the other Virtual switches?
- How does this affect local (127.0.0.1) loopback addressing?

**Update**

When I run `ipconfig /all` I still see all of the vEthernet switches but I do not see what used to be my default interface the one just called "Ethernet", listed.

Am I using it?

What is going on?

Comment: Its the virtual ethernet adapter for Hyper-V>>>>>https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/

Comment: Run ipconfig /all

Comment: Your computer is using your switch, but your VM's are using the virtual switches. They are Hyper-V devices and can generally be ignored as long as things are working right. the 172.16.0.0/12 addresses are private IP addressing space used by your VM system for various purposes and is used by default because although 172.16.0.0/12 is private IP space, but few device use that be default and typically use something in the 192.168.0.0/16 or 10.0.0.0/8 IP address ranges.

Comment: Beginning with Windows 10 v1709 and later releases a new switch named Default Switch is created whenever the Hyper-V role is installed, aimed to provide an easy networking solution for virtual machines, the Default Switch allows virtual machines to share the host’s network connection using NAT similar to the way of Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).

Comment: The Hyper-V Default Switch will randomly use one these IP address ranges based on the host system IP address: Start IP: 192.168.0.0 – End IP: 192.168.255.255     Start IP: 172.17.0.0 – End IP: 172.31.255.255

Comment: But it looks like my server itself is *also* using the NIC and I do not want that to happen. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Vethernet switches are part of the system allowing network access for the VMs and other aspects of Hyper-V.

Do not remove or modify them unless you know what you are doing.